# Enforcing that an array within an object literal can only contain keys of the outer object

Tags: typescript, keyof

I have the following Interface definitions.

```
interface IComponents {
  root: IComponent,
  [key: string]: IComponent,
}

interface IComponent {
  type: string,
  children?: Array<keyof IComponents>;
}
```

I want that the "children" properties accept only keys of defined Components.
in the case of the "root.children"-property it should only accept root, button1 and button2:

```
const list: IComponents = {
  root: {
    type: 'panel',
    children: ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']
  },
  button1: {
    type: 'button'
  },
  button2: {
    type: 'button'
  },
}
```

But it accepts also arbitrary strings, like in the example "**button3**".

Answer (score 0):

> But it accepts also arbitrary strings, like in the example "button3".

## Reason:

You have

```
interface IComponents {
  root: IComponent,
  [key: string]: IComponent,
}
```

so `keyof IComponents` resolves to `'root' | string` or effectively `string`. You almost always *never* want to have well defined names and `string` indexers [in the same group](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html).

## Solution

I would reconsider a non-cyclic design. The following:

```
const list: IComponents = {
  root: {
    type: 'panel',
    children: ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']
  },
  button1: {
    type: 'button'
  },
  button2: {
    type: 'button'
  },
}
```

The type of `list` *depends* on the assigned object. Ideally you would figure out some way that type *enforces* what can be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single `IComponents` type you can define that includes all (and only) component lists that are internally consistent in the sense that the `children` lists only refer to defined components; this would require a form of existential types.  However, you can define a generic type `IComponents<K>` that represents a valid component list with a specific key list `K`, and this will allow you to define functions that are generic in a type parameter `K` and accept an `IComponents<K>` and thus can be called on any valid component list.  For example:

```
type IComponents<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: IComponent<K>;
} & {
  // Needed for contextual typing to work.
  // https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27586 might remove the need for this.
  [n: string]: IComponent<K>
};

interface IComponent<K extends string> {
  type: string,
  children?: Array<K>;
}

function processComponents<K extends string>(arg: IComponents<K>) {
  // ...
}

// OK
processComponents({
  root: {
    type: 'panel',
    children: ['button1', 'button2']
  },
  button1: {
    type: 'button'
  },
  button2: {
    type: 'button'
  },
});

// Error (unfortunately it doesn't pinpoint the mistake)
processComponents({
  root: {
    type: 'panel',
    children: ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']
  },
  button1: {
    type: 'button'
  },
  button2: {
    type: 'button'
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But I think this should be available natively in TS.

Comment: Don't we all wish TypeScript had everything built-in... You can always upvote [the suggestion for existential types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  In the meantime, if you run into a specific problem with this solution, let me know and I will see if I can find a workaround.